# The dimension command doesn't match with the dimension of this dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dimensions

When I run this code:

```
library(ISLR)
train = (year%%2 == 0)
test = !train
Auto.test = Auto[train,]
Auto.test
```

I have the following output (The three dots were given by me):

```
mpg cylinders displacement horsepower weight acceleration year origin                              name
1   18.0         8        307.0        130   3504         12.0   70      1         chevrolet chevelle malibu
2   15.0         8        350.0        165   3693         11.5   70      1                 buick skylark 320
3   18.0         8        318.0        150   3436         11.0   70      1                plymouth satellite
4   16.0         8        304.0        150   3433         12.0   70      1                     amc rebel sst
5   17.0         8        302.0        140   3449         10.5   70      1                       ford torino
...
199 33.0         4         91.0         53   1795         17.4   76      3                       honda civic
200 20.0         6        225.0        100   3651         17.7   76      1                    dodge aspen se
201 18.0         6        250.0         78   3574         21.0   76      1                 ford granada ghia
202 18.5         6        250.0        110   3645         16.2   76      1                pontiac ventura sj
203 17.5         6        258.0         95   3193         17.8   76      1                     amc pacer d/l
204 29.5         4         97.0         71   1825         12.2   76      2                 volkswagen rabbit
205 32.0         4         85.0         70   1990         17.0   76      3                      datsun b-210
206 28.0         4         97.0         75   2155         16.4   76      3                    toyota corolla
207 26.5         4        140.0         72   2565         13.6   76      1                        ford pinto
208 20.0         4        130.0        102   3150         15.7   76      2                         volvo 245
209 13.0         8        318.0        150   3940         13.2   76      1        plymouth volare premier v8
210 19.0         4        120.0         88   3270         21.9   76      2                       peugeot 504
 [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 99 rows ]
```

But when I try to discover the dimension of *Auto.test*:

```
dim(Auto.test)
```

I have

```
[1] 210   9
```

Why the dimension command didn't give me the real dimension of this dataframe? The dimension command gives me 210 rows and 9 columns. The problem is the rows aren't correct, following the dataframe we should have 210+99 rows

Comment: What do you mean by real dimension? `Auto.test` has only 210 rows but their row numbers are distorted because of subset.

Comment: If you don't include column and row names those dimensions seem correct - what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @jared_mamrot please see my edit

Comment: @RonakShah I explained better in the edit

Comment: @user75086 No, those are row numbers. Check row after row number 29 it jumps to 58.

Comment: try doing `(rownames(Auto.test) <- NULL)` Now does it match the dimensions according to your eyes? Even before you do this, the dimension given is correct